# PHP objects in array increase

Tags: php, for-loop

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php for($i=0;$i<count((array)$params->get("fields"));$i++){
        echo "<li style=\"background-image:url('". $params->get("fields")->image ."');\" data-target=\"#itemedia_imageslider-".$moduleId."\" data-slide-to=\"".$i."\" ".(($i+1 == 1)? "class='active'":"")."></li>";
    }?>
</ol>
```

Hi, i fave thos code for carousel indicators. Example when i have in carousel 3 items this show 3 list items. I have problem with code `background-image:url('". $params->get("fields")->image ."')` . How i can add value $i to $params->get("fields").

thanks

Comment: `$params->get("fields")[$i]->...`

Answer (score 0):

$params has any method called $params->set?

Or you can create a copy of this object and add more information in there:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<?php
    $newFields = [];
    $fields = $params->get("fields");

    foreach ($fields as $index => $field) {
        $newFields[$index] = $field;
        $newFields[$index]->index_value = $index;

        echo "<li style=\"background-image:url('". $field->image ."');\" data-target=\"#itemedia_imageslider-".$moduleId."\" data-slide-to=\"".$index."\" ".(($index + 1 == 1)? "class='active'":"")."></li>";
    }
}?>
```

and use the variable $newFields whit the index value after in code